# problem when displays the all values in the table column

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm having a problem displaying the sum of all the values in a table column in the database.

first, I have 5 values in the database as follows:
Click the image below.
[image]

I will add up the 5 values normally, if you look at the value if you add up all the results are 19.

second, I managed to add up all the values with the following code:

```
            <?php $query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM nkriteria "); ?>
            <?php while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
                <?php $result[]=$data['nilai']; ?>
                <?php $result_value=array_sum($result); ?>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><?php echo $result_value; ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
```

third, when I display it in the table, the value is like a loop. Here are the results in the table:
Click the image below.
[image]

The question is, how can I display the number 19 only? because the number 19 is the sum of all the values.

Comment: Do you have a loop which displays the values above it, could you do the sum in that loop rather than have a new loop (plus SQL) just for the total.  If not, look into using `SUM(nilsa)` in your SQL so you can just fetch the total rather than needing a loop.

Comment: If you realy must use images, don't rely on images in some other site, upload images here directly and display them as well not just as links - if you want people to provide answers (for free) make it simple for them to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the $fetch array query is always true thus $result_value is executed each time the loop is iterated. try the following snippet.

```
        <?php $query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM nkriteria "); ?>
        <?php $result_value = '';
        <?php while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { ?>
            <?php $result[]=$data['nilai']; ?>
            <?php $result_value=array_sum($result); ?>
        <?php } ?>
         <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $result_value; ?></td>
        </tr>
```